# Проверка на наличие текста в посте wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Здравствуйте, подскажите как проверить есть ли текст в статье, именно текст поста, а не цитату. Нужно для того что бы вывести определенный текст, если пост не содержит текста (а только картинки например)
например для проверки наличия цитаты есть условный тег has_excerpt, а для текста что можно использовать?

Comment: Ни чего не могу понять?? Все заработало, но делая все тоже самое на чистом wp перестает работать, не догоняю почему. Тема одна и та же,  все файлы темы идентичны, разные только домены и то что один сайт чистая установка wp. В чем может быть проблема? http://iccwlikr.bget.ru/ это чистый, а это тот на котором тестил http://toplovskyi.t1ll.ru/

Comment: В общем связать два хука не получилось (пока) по отдельности оба работают хорошо

Answer (score 1):

можно поставить хук на шаблонный тег

```
the_content
```

например так:

```
function the_empty_content( $text ){
    // $text это текст поста с которым можно сделать что требуется
    // в том числе проверить на длину строки
    if (empty($text)) {
       $text = "Определенный текст";
    }
   return $text;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'the_empty_content');
```

Comment: Спасибо!! Огромное!! Чет сам с другой стороны пошел (все пытался через условные теги)

Comment: Правда в таком виде как у вас немножко не правильно работает, т.е. если статья содержит хотя картинку, то она выводится. Я добавил еще фильтр на вывод картинок, тогда работает, но не знаю может есть проще вариант, что бы не использовать два фильтра, как то в одном можно сделать, сорри если что, я только учусь.

Comment: <pre>
       function htm_image_content_filter($content){
    $content = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "", $content);
    return $content;
    }

    function the_empty_content( $text ){
    // $text это текст поста с которым можно сделать что требуется
    // в том числе проверить на длину строки
    if (empty($text)) {
       the_tags('');
    }
    return $text;
    }
    add_filter('the_content', 'the_empty_content');
    </pre>